# What is this C function doing?

Tags: c, function

I understand that it's going to take in a number and return a character. I understand what each line of code is doing, but I can't really express what it's doing overall in a meaningful way. Any ideas?

```
int function(uint64_t P1) {
    uint64_t L1 = P1;
    uint32_t L2 = 1;

    while (L1 > 15) {
        L2 = (uint64_t)L2 << 4;
        L1 = L1 >> 4;
    }
    uint32_t L3 = 0;

    while (L2 != 0) {
        L1 = P1;
        uint32_t L4 = 0;

        L4 = L1 % L2;
        uint64_t L5 = (uint64_t)L4;
        sub_function(L1 / L2);
        L3++;
        P1 = L5;
        L2 = (uint64_t)L2 >> 4;
    }
    L1 = L3;

    return L1;
}

void sub_function(uint64_t P1) {
    if (P1 <= 9) {
        printf("%c", P1 + 48);
    } else {
        printf("%c", P1 + 55);
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears to be conversion from decimal to hexadecimal

Comment: Given that `L2` is only 32 bits, I am not so sure about that.

Comment: @Gerhardh: I came to my conclusion empirically. Without more meaningful names and comments, it's difficult to say otherwise what is going on.

Comment: @Gerhardh  If the number contains data above 32 bits then it will return 0 and print nothing. For numbers that fit into 32 bits it will print the hex representation and return the number of hexadecimal digits printed.

Comment: why cast a 32 bit uint to 64bit then shift and write it back to 32bit? (see L2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code accepts a decimal value and prints the hexadecimal representation.

[Try it out yourself](http://ideone.com/YWVHOT)

In C we can use the `%x` (`%X`) format specifier flag to `printf` to do it for us:

```
printf("%X", 16); // 10
printf("\n");
printf("%X", 42); // 2A
```

If you're using a C++ compiler, we can instead use the [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) stream manipulation flag on `iostream` to achieve the same result:

```
std::cout << std::hex << 16 << std::endl; // 10
std::cout << std::hex << 42 << std::endl; // 2a
```

Comment: Not to be a pedant, but why give the OP a solution / alternative in C++?

Comment: @KevinDTimm: With questions like these, the asker is typically new enough that they don't recognize when they're using a C++ compiler, so I instinctively assumed as much.

Comment: They've tagged the question as `c` and their compiler shouldn't matter - your example won't be of much use to a `c` programmer or in a `c` class.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Fair point. I've edited the post with more C-specific information. I still think the C++ bit is useful, though.